# Confusion on upper and lower lebesgue integrals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

This may be somewhat a repeat, but in this question, I'm asking for more of a conceptual answer rather than a proof.  We define the Lebesgue integral, for a measurable function $f:X \longrightarrow [0,\infty]$ and a measurable set $E$, as 
$$\int_E f d \mu =  \sup\big{\{}\int_E s d\mu : 0 \le s \le f,   s \text{ is simple}  \big{\}}.$$

This is also defined as the lower Lebesgue integral (similar to the lower Riemann integral).  An upper Lebesgue integral as $$\inf \big{\{} \int_E s d \mu : f \le s, s\text{ is simple} \big{\}}.$$

To my understanding, these two don't always equal each other. If this is true, why do we only treat one of them as the proper Lebesgue integral?  Do all of the theorems involving the upper integral hold with the lower integral definition?  What is preferable about the given definition?

Comment: One issue is that simple functions are, by definition, the measurable functions with finite range, and therefore when you try to find a simple function on $\Bbb R$ which stays above, say, $e^{-x^2}$ you only have functions with infinite integral.

Comment: @Gae.S will we ever get a case where both upper and lower integrals agree and they are both finite?  or in every case where they disagree, the lower is finite and the upper is infinite?

Comment: For $f\ge0$, they agree if and only if the lower Lebesgue integral is $\infty$ or $f$ is zero outside a set of finite measure. I presume that you should obtain an equivalent notion (again, for $f\ge0$) if you define the upper integral as $\sup\left\{ \inf\left\{ \int \phi\,d\mu\,:\, \phi\text{ simple }\land \phi=0\text{ outside of }E\land \phi\ge f\text{ on }E \right\}\,:\, \mu(E)<\infty\right\}$. But then it is not true that the sums in the upper integral dominate the sums in the lower integral.

Comment: @Gae.S.   I was thinking about this question the other day.   Would another reason we don't use the "upper lebesgue integral" as a definition is because, we cannot define a simple function that is above say $e^x$.  Since $s$ is finite, there is a greatest value, and a function like $e^x$ will always have values greater than $s$

Comment: You have a point. I'm not as much concerned with $e^x$, because $\inf\emptyset=\infty$, but I am concerned with unbounded functions of finite integral, like $x^{-1/2}$ on $[0,1]$. In light of this, I propose that the two integrals coincide on some non-negative function $f$ if and only if the lower integral is $\infty$ or $f$ is bounded outside of a set of measure $0$ and zero outside of a set of finite measure.

Comment: I propose that the alternative definition for $f\ge 0$ should be $\sup\{\inf\{\int\phi\,d\mu\,:\,\phi\text{ simple }\land\phi=0\text{ outside of }E\land \phi\ge f\text{ on }E\}\,:\,\mu(E)<\infty\land \left.f\right\rvert_E\text{ bounded}\}$.