# Confusion about different definitions of integral in measure theory.

Tags: measure-theory

I've recently noticed that the definition of the integral in my measure theory course seems to be quite different from the usual definition, in particular the one another one of my courses uses. What really confuses me though, is that it seems to have much stronger properties than it should have, going by other texts.

So the definition I saw in my measure theory course notably assumes $\mu$ to be a Radon (outer!) measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, meaning it is Borel regular and finite on any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Also, $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is assumed to be $\mu$-measurable. We then define a simple function $g : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ to be a function of the form
$$
g(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} d_i \chi_{A_i}(x)
$$
for $d_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A_i \subseteq \Omega$ mutually disjoint with $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i = \Omega$. This already is different from the usual definition of a simple function, where the sum is only finite. Then the integral of a nonnegative simple $\mu$-measurable function $g: \Omega \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is defined as
$$
\int_{\Omega} g \ d\mu = \begin{cases} \sum_{0 \leq y \leq \infty} y \mu(g^{-1}) \leq \infty & g < \infty \ \mu \text{-a.e.} \newline \infty & \text{otherwise} \end{cases},
$$
where $0 \cdot \infty = 0$ and the sum is well-defined since the range of a simple function is at most countable. Then we say a simple, $\mu$-measurable function $g : \Omega\to [-\infty, \infty]$ is $\mu$-integrable if either the integral of $g^+$ or $g^-$ in the above sense is finite. If so, then we define its integral as
$$
\int_{\Omega} g \ d\mu = \int_{\Omega} g^+ \ d\mu - \int_{\Omega} g^- \ d\mu
$$
given that $|g| < \infty$ almost everywhere (otherwise we set it as $\pm\infty$ if $\mu(g^{-1}\{\pm \infty\})> 0$). Finally, for $f : \Omega \to [-\infty, \infty]$ $\mu$-measurable we define the upper integral as
$$
\overline{\int_{\Omega}} = \inf \left\{ \int_{\Omega} g \ d\mu \mid g \text{ is } \mu \text{-integrable and simple with } g \geq f \ \mu-\text{a.e.} \right\}
$$
and the lower integral as
$$
\underline{\int_{\Omega}} = \sup \left\{ \int_{\Omega} g \ d\mu \mid g \text{ is } \mu \text{-integrable and simple with } g \leq f \ \mu-\text{a.e.} \right\}
$$
to conclude by calling $f$ $\mu$-integrable if the upper and the lower integrals coincide. Then the notes go on to state that **any** nonnegative measurable function is integrable in this sense.

On the other hand, in my course on Fourier theory, there is a small recap of measure theory where the definitions are quite different. First of all, we are in the setting of classical measures and consider an arbitrary measure space $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$. Then, simple functions are defined as finite sums
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n a_j \chi_{E_j},
$$
where $a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $E_1, \dots, E_n$ satisfy $\mu(E_i) < \infty$. Then, we define the integral of a simple function $s$ as
$$
\int_X s \ d\mu = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \mu(E_j).
$$
Next, the integral for a measurable $f : X \to [0, \infty]$ is defined as
$$
\int_X f \ d\mu = \sup \left\{ \int_X s \ d \mu \mid s \text{ is simple and } s(x) \leq f(x) \text{ for all } x \in X \right\}
$$
and a general measurable $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is called integrable if either the integral of $f^+$ or $f^-$ is finite. If it is integrable, its integral is simply defined as the difference of the integrals of $f^+$ and $f^-$.
In this definition, we didn't use the upper integral at all. After looking at some other textbooks, for example Terry Tao's Introduction to Measure Theory, it seems like there is a reason that the upper integral is not usually used in the definition. Tao uses a similar construction and claims that $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to [0, \infty]$ measurable needs to be bounded and vanishing outside a finite measure set for the upper and lower integrals to coincide. This in particular seems very different from the statement in the former construction, that said **any** nonnegative measurable function is "integrable" (where integrable means that the upper and lower integrals coincide).

I'm getting lost in all the different terminology and assumptions that are made, so I can't see how the two constructions relate. Why do we require the upper and lower integrals to coincide in the first but not in the second? Does this result in a different notion of integrability? Is one stronger than the other? Does it have anything to do with the assumption that $\mu$ is Radon in the first?

I have an exam on both of these classes in the summer, so I'd really appreciate any help on this.

---

**Update:** It seems that the main difference comes from the fact that my measure theory course defined simple functions as countable sums (resulting in functions with countable range) while the other resources I saw define them as finite sums (resulting in functions with finite range). The former definition seems to be following the text by Evans and Gariepy while I've seen the latter definition in many other textbooks, like Tao. I think if you define the upper and lower integrals via simple functions with countable range, they match for all non-negative measurable functions. If you define them using simple functions with finite range, you get functions whose lower integral is finite but whose upper integral is infinite (an example being $e^{-x^2}$). At least this is the conclusion I drew from [posts like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607328/confusion-on-upper-and-lower-lebesgue-integrals?noredirect=1). I'm not sure whether this is the full story though.

Comment: The point of having upper and lower integrals is that they are always defined, even if the function is not measurable. There are applications in which that is useful. Your measure theory course seems to look only at $\mu$-measurable functions, but otherwise these integrals should always coincide. Both your courses use nonstandard notions of "integrable"; usually a function is integrable only if both the positive and the negative parts have a finite integral.